# Метод класса интерфейса не сохраняется файл в выбранную папку

Tags: python, сокет, pyqt

Возникла проблема с сохранением файла по указанному пути.
Вот часть кода которая не исполняется да конца (т.е. ответ от сервера она получает, а дальше тишина, хотя должен формироваться датафрейм для последующего сохранения в файл):

```
# принятие ответа сервера
    def recv_msg(self):
        data = self.sock.recv(10240)
        data = pickle.loads(data, encoding='utf-8')
        rep_file = data.to_csv('report_df.csv', index=False)
        target_fld = self.get_folder()
        os.path.join(str(target_fld), rep_file)
        print('file upload')
        self.sock.close()
```

Вот весь код в модуле:

```
import sys
import os
import socket
import pickle
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from upload_client_gui import Ui_MainWindow

class gui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))

        self.download_folder = None
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get_folder)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.send_msg)

    # выбор даты выгружаемого отчета 
    def calendar_date(self):
        date = self.ui.calendarWidget.selectedDate()
        string_date = str(date.toPyDate())
        return string_date

    # открывается проводник для выбора папки в которую будет сохраняться файл
    def get_folder(self):
        try:
            self.download_folder = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Выберете папку для сохранения')
            os.chdir(self.download_folder)
            print(self.download_folder)
        except:
            pass

    # отправка даты на сервер через сокет
    def send_msg(self):
        msg = self.calendar_date()
        print(msg)
        self.sock.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))

    # принятие ответа сервера
    def recv_msg(self):
        data = self.sock.recv(10240)
        data = pickle.loads(data, encoding='utf-8')
        rep_file = data.to_csv('report_df.csv', index=False)
        target_fld = self.get_folder()
        os.path.join(str(target_fld), rep_file)
        print('file upload')
        self.sock.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = gui()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Выбор папки работает, возвращается абсолютный путь, запрос и ответ сокета тоже есть.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться где у меня проблема.

Comment: Что значит "не исполняется до конца"? Эта фраза может означать что угодно. Опишите ситуацию чётко - что вы ожидаете и что происходит на самом деле. А вообще метод `to_csv` возвращает `None`, так что в `rep_file` у вас будет `None`, а кроме того вы не пользуетесь результатом вызова функции `os.path.join`. Хотя если вы подаёте ей на вход `None`, у вас всё-равно должна выйти ошибка. А если выходит ошибка, вы по правилам должны поместить её полный текст прямо в вопросе.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо информацию про `None`, описание дополнил. Можешь объяснить как надо, если написанные варианты не верны?

Comment: Я в `pyqt` не очень понимаю. Может там исключение выбрасывается, но вы же там исключения не ловите, я не знаю, что в этом случае в `pyqt` происходит, показывает ли оно ошибки. А что касается как поменять код - я не понимаю, что вы хотите, чтобы этот код делал, зачем вы полный путь файла собираете, если вы его не используете.

Comment: @CrazyElf я обертывал этот метод в `try: ... except:`, но результатов не было, т.е. метод просто останавливается, видимо из-за `to_csv`. А как еще это сделать, я еще не придумал.

Comment: А точно не на `data = self.sock.recv(10240)` ваш код висит?

Comment: @CrazyElf вот теперь я совсем запутался.... `data` не выводится в терминал, буду рад любым предложениям, и пойду дальше гуглить...

Comment: Поищите тут на СО вопросы-ответы по сокетам, там много разных подводных камней, я помню не раз тут работу с сокетами в питоне обсуждали.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо за помощь, буду разбираться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я разобрался в своих ошибках! Нужно было поместить отправку и прием сообщения в один метод, и немного переписать создание файла в выбранной папке. Надеюсь кому-нибудь пригодится:

```
import sys
import os
import socket
import pickle
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from upload_client_gui import Ui_MainWindow

class Gui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))

        self.download_folder = None
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get_folder)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.send_msg)

    # выбор даты выгружаемого отчета
    def calendar_date(self):
        date = self.ui.calendarWidget.selectedDate()
        string_date = str(date.toPyDate())
        return string_date

    # открывается проводник для выбора папки в которую будет сохраняться файл
    def get_folder(self):
        try:
            self.download_folder = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Выберете папку для сохранения')
            self.download_folder = self.download_folder.replace('/', '\\') + '\\'
        except:
            pass

    # отправка даты на сервер и прием информации с сервера через сокет
    def send_msg(self):
        msg = self.calendar_date()
        self.sock.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))

        data = self.sock.recv(10240)
        data = pickle.loads(data, encoding='utf-8')
        try:
            target_fld = self.download_folder
            data.to_csv(os.path.join(str(target_fld), 'report_df.csv'), index=False)
            self.sock.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Gui()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

возможно ошибка в буфере -> 1024->(0)<-

socket.recv(10240)будет считывать не более 10240 байт, блокируя, если нет данных, ожидающих чтения.

socket.recv также будет заканчиваться пустой строкой, если соединение будет закрыто или возникнет ошибка и вы ничего не узнаете о неполадках.
короче, дынные отправлены, но их размер невелик, а буфер не забит.
попробуй изменить размер буфера.

Comment: В версии без GUI сокет с этим же размером буфера работает исправно. На всякий случай решил попробовать ваш совет и поиграть с этим значением, результат не изменился.